# Integral differential equation solving

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have following set of equations:
$\dot{x_1}(s) = x_2(s)$
$\dot{x_2}(s) = \int_s^L{x_1(s)}ds $
How can I solve this with known boundary conditions $x_1(L)$ and $x_2(0)$

If the second equation would have been
$\dot{x_2}(s) = \int_0^s{x_1(s)} $
then I would have considered   $\int_0^s{x_1(s)} = x_3$ which in turn on differentiating with s would give:
$\dot{x_3}(s) = x_1(s)$
$\dot{x_1}(s) = x_2(s)$
$\dot{x_2}(s) = x_3(s) $
these equations can be solved.
Any ideas.
My end goal is to numerically solve this equations.

Comment: Can't you flip your s to L integral as -(L to s), then split? Is L defined with respect to zero (positive or negative)?

Comment: Both s and L are positive and 's<=L'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still set $$x_3(s)=\int_s^L x_1(t)\,dt.$$ Only that now differentiation gives $\dot x_3=-x_1$ and the known boundary value is $x_3(L)=0$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand how $\dot{x_3} = -x_1 $.

Comment: Got it. Used fundamental theorem of calculus.